# Find the set of all points that are contained in a moving sphere

Tags: computational-geometry, r-tree

I have a finite set `P` of several thousands of sparse points in the 3d space and a moving sphere `S` of fixed radius. For every given moment `t` I know `S_t`, i.e. the volume of space occupied by the sphere. I don't know beforehand in which direction `S` is going to move next. How can I find the subset `Q_t` of all the points contained in `S_t`?

I thought to do as follows:

1. Put all the points in an R-tree and compute `Q_0`
2. For every t > 0, compute the relative complements

   `N_t = S_t \ S_(t-1)` and `M_t = S_(t-1) \ S_t`
3. Then, I query the R-tree for all the points contained in the relative complements, `P(N_t)` and `P(M_t)`
4. Finally, I update the result as:

   `Q_t = Q_(t-1) + P(N_t) - P(M_t)`

Does this work? Is there a more efficient way to compute this?

Also, are there any libraries that allow me to efficiently solve this?

Comment: is the sphere moving by some bounded increment?  You might periodically find all points within some larger sphere (big enough to encompass the next `n` increments..), so reduce the search for a few subsequent increments.

Comment: What are **sparse** (?) points in 3d? Why can't you just query S_t every time? The complements yield a much more complex geometry than a sphere for querying. Also, efficiency will depend a lot on implementation quality of the search tree.

Comment: How many points inside the sphere do you expect ? This can make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the points in a kD tree (k=3) and perform fixed-radius near-neighbor searches.

I am not sure that a strategy trying to exploit the small increments and solve for one position using the previous one(s) will really pay.